# get the position after setState in flutter

Tags: flutter

Below is my simple example. After press the button, the container's position will change. Are there any methods to print the container's new position of dx and dy automatically after press the button?

```
class Data extends StatefulWidget {
  DataState createState() => DataState();
}

class DataState extends State<Data> {
  double height = 10.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                height += 10.0;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: height,
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              height: 25
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MediaQuery` and `Size`

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      height: size.height / 10,
      width: size.width,
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: color),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I did not describe my requisition clearly. I need some methods to listen the position change of the container so that the system could print the new position immediately after press the button rather than users' interactions with the system.

Comment: In this case you could define a variable that contains the initial value of the position, and when setState is executed you also change this variable, or define another temporary variable.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Container` or any widget is moving dynamically, you can get its location/position using `Rect Getter`

https://pub.dev/packages/rect_getter